# Get a php value in a class in html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get a value from php into an input box like this:

```
<input type="text" name="IPs" class="Input" value="<?php echo $ips; ?>" readonly>
```

When i look at the page the textbox is empty.
I think it may be because i have `$ips = $ips . "\n" . $ip;` in a php function called `public function resolve($url)`, in a class called `class CF`. The $ip is only retrieved in that function.
I have no idea how i am supposed to get the php value inside the textbox.
Can someone help please.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if you can't show us your source code?

Comment: Do some little debugging. Try printing the value of $ips on the page without rendering it in the input field. If it is empty, it might mean that you are not getting the value from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$ips = $ips. "\n". $ip;
echo '<input type="text" name="IPs" class="Input" value="'.$ips.'" readonly>';
```

Comment: Don't forget to click "This answer is useful" and close your topic